# firestore data not being displayed on iphone screen in xcode app

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I’m new to writing iOs apps and I'm struggling with displaying data from a firestore database onto my iPhone screen in the app. The frontend is being written in Swift via xcode. The intended function of the below code is that each time a barcode is scanned with a barcode number (UPC) that is in a firestore collection called “known_UPC” , the UPC of that product shows up on a “history” screen.

However, when I put the app on my iPhone and test it by scanning a product with a barcode that is in the known_UPC collection, the productDetailView shows up as expected. But then when I exit it, instead of seeing the UPC in a list on the HistoryView screen, I see nothing.

Below is the code and the logs when I scan a product that exists in the known_UPC collection.

**HistoryView Xcode file:**

```
//
//  HistoryView.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct HistoryView: View {
    
    @Binding var isBarcodeScannerOpen: Bool
    @State var isProductDetailOpen = false
    @State var scannedBarcodeDocumentID: String = ""
    @State var scannedBarcode: String = ""
    @State var userData: [BarcodeData] = [] // Data from Firestore
    @State private var showScanFirstProductScreen = true
    @State private var dataLoaded = false
    
    struct BarcodeData: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let UPC: String
        let productName: String
    }
    
    
    func fetchDataFromFirestore() {
        // Update so after we check if the user exists, we check if there are any scanned barcode documents that exist. If no, show a blank screen with "hello message"
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let usersCollection = db.collection("users")

        usersCollection.document(user.uid).getDocument { document, error in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                if let barcodeScanned = document.data()?["barcode_scanned"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    var tempUserData: [BarcodeData] = []
                    
                    dataLoaded = true
                    
                    for data in barcodeScanned {
                        if let UPC = data["UPC"] as? String {
                            // Fetch product name from known_UPC collection
                            db.collection("known_UPC").document(UPC).getDocument {
                                knownDocument, knownError in
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    print("UPC in problem area is", UPC)
                                    if let knownDocument = knownDocument, knownDocument.exists {
                                        if let productName = knownDocument.data()?["product_name"] as? String {
                                            showScanFirstProductScreen = false
                                            tempUserData.append(BarcodeData(UPC: UPC, productName: productName))
                                            print("productName in problem area is", productName)
                                            print("data loaded status in problem area is", dataLoaded)
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        showScanFirstProductScreen = false
                                        print("This product is not in the known_UPC collection, UPC is", UPC)
                                        print("data loaded status in else statement of problem area is", dataLoaded)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    userData = tempUserData
                }
            } else {
                dataLoaded = true
                print("User does not exist")
                print("data loaded status where user doesn't exist is", dataLoaded)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func barcodeScanned(barcode: String) {
        scannedBarcodeDocumentID = storeBarcode(barcode: barcode)
        isBarcodeScannerOpen = false
        scannedBarcode = barcode
        self.isProductDetailOpen = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
                Color(red: 241, green: 242, blue: 248).ignoresSafeArea()
                NavigationLink(destination: CameraControllerView(isPresented: $isBarcodeScannerOpen, barcode: barcodeScanned(barcode:)), isActive: $isBarcodeScannerOpen) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetailView(scannedBarcodeDocumentID: scannedBarcodeDocumentID, barcode: scannedBarcode), isActive: $isProductDetailOpen) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    if showScanFirstProductScreen {
                        Text("Scan your first product")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    } else {
                        if dataLoaded {
                            List(userData) { data in
                                Text(data.UPC)
                            }
                            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                            .background(Color.white)
                            
                        } else {
                            //ProgressView("Loading...")
                            Text("Data loaded status in else statement of vstack is false")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer().frame(height: 20)
            }
            .onAppear {
                fetchDataFromFirestore()
            }
            }
        
    }
}

struct HistoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HistoryView(isBarcodeScannerOpen: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

**Xcode logs**

```
UPC in problem area is 0851557003132

productName in problem area is Algae Renew Deep Conditioning Mask

data loaded status in problem area is true
```

I’ve used several log messages / text on the screen to isolate the problem area. The VStack in the Navigation view has a set of if statements, and the code seems to be correctly entering the if statement where the UPC is supposed to be displayed on the screen. I’ve deduced this because the “Scan your first product” message disappears from the screen after a barcode has been scanned and the “data loaded status in problem area is true” message appears in the logs.

Therefore, it’s confusing to me why the UPC number isn’t appearing on the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is userData you're trying to display, I guess you are never seeing it because you are updating it outside the DispatchQueue. Since that is concurrent you never know if that is going to e run first or later. Best guess is the userData = tempUserData is always run first, when tempUserData is empty basically. Why don't you use userData inside the DispatchQueue directly maybe?

Comment: @MatBuompy, please post your comment as answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar question.

Comment: I'll do It tomorrow in the morning (I live in Italy). Thank you!

Comment: @RobertG I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is userData you're trying to display, I guess you are never seeing it because you are updating it outside the DispatchQueue. Since that is concurrent is very likely the userData = tempUserData instruction is always run first, when tempUserData is empty basically. You could even use userData inside the DispatchQueue directly like this:

```
for data in barcodeScanned {
                    if let UPC = data["UPC"] as? String {
                        // Fetch product name from known_UPC collection
                        db.collection("known_UPC").document(UPC).getDocument {
                            knownDocument, knownError in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print("UPC in problem area is", UPC)
                                if let knownDocument = knownDocument, knownDocument.exists {
                                    if let productName = knownDocument.data()?["product_name"] as? String {
                                        showScanFirstProductScreen = false
                                        userData.append(BarcodeData(UPC: UPC, productName: productName)) // <-- Use userData here directly
                                        print("productName in problem area is", productName)
                                        print("data loaded status in problem area is", dataLoaded)
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    showScanFirstProductScreen = false
                                    print("This product is not in the known_UPC collection, UPC is", UPC)
                                    print("data loaded status in else statement of problem area is", dataLoaded)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I hope to have helped you!